# FormGroup.patchValue is not updating the text box view for null value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have one text box form control and i am getting value from back end then assigning to text box value using patch value.if i type anything in text box and i click button then it fetches null value from back end but the text box view is not getting updated with null value ,still showing the text i have typed.

c-sectioncomponent.html

```
<div [formGroup]="plf.cueForm">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row form-group ct-margin-b-20">
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let ctrl of displayControls;">
                        <div *ngIf="!plf.state_defn[ctrl.id]" [class]="layoutCls">
                          <app-c-textbox *ngIf="ctrl.type == 'text' && ctrl.event != '' && ctrl.event != undefined" [formControlName]="ctrl.id" [label]="ctrl.label"
                            [format]="ctrl.format" (textBoxOnEnter)="plf.handleEvent(ctrl.event)" [mandatory]="ctrl.mandatory"
                            [InputLength]="ctrl.InputLength" [inputFormat]="ctrl.inputFormat">
                          </app-c-textbox>
                          </div>
                 </div>
            /div>
```

c-sectioncomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PlfDataSourceService } from '../../controls/plf-data-source.service'
import { PlfHelpSourceService } from '../../controls/plf-help-source.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-c-section',
  templateUrl: './c-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./c-section.component.css']
})
export class CSectionComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: String = "";
  @Input() controls: any[];
  @Input() collapsed: String;
  @Input() btnID: String;
  @Input() helpFlag: boolean = false;
  @Input() hidden: String;
  hiddenFlag: String = 'false';
  collapseSection: String = 'false';
  displayControls: any[];
  plf: any;
  randomNumber: any;
  @Input() columns: any;

  constructor(private plfMain: PlfDataSourceService,
    private plfHelp: PlfHelpSourceService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.collapseSection ='false';

    if (this.hidden != undefined) {
      this.hiddenFlag = this.hidden;
    }
    if (this.collapsed != undefined) {
      if (this.collapsed == 'true') 
      {
        this.collapseSection = 'true';
      }
      if (this.collapsed == 'false') 
      {
        this.collapseSection = 'false';
      }
    }
    if (this.helpFlag) {
      this.plf = this.plfHelp
    }
    else {
      this.plf = this.plfMain
  }

    this.randomNumber = this.plfMain.getRandom();

    if (this.controls != undefined) {
      this.controls.forEach(element => {

        this.plf.cueForm.removeControl(element.id);
        if (element.mandatory != undefined) {
          if (element.type == 'datetime') {
            this.plf.cueForm.addControl(element.dateId, new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
            this.plf.cueForm.addControl(element.timeId, new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
          }
          else {
            this.plf.cueForm.addControl(element.id, new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
          }
        }
        else {
          if (element.type == 'datetime') {
            this.plf.cueForm.addControl(element.dateId, new FormControl('', []));
            this.plf.cueForm.addControl(element.timeId, new FormControl('', []));
          }
          else {
            this.plf.cueForm.addControl(element.id, new FormControl('', []));
          }
        }
        if (element.type == 'datetime') {
          this.plf.controlLabel[element.dateId] = element.label;
          this.plf.controlLabel[element.timeId] = element.label;
        }
        else {
          this.plf.controlLabel[element.id] = element.label;
        }

      });

      this.displayControls = this.controls.filter(
        (element) => {
          if (element.type != "hidden")
            return true;
        }
      )



    }
  }


}
```

ctextboxcomponent.html

```
<i *ngIf="mandatory" class="mandatory-field">*&nbsp;</i><label>{{label}}</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control ct-input" 
    [value]="val"
    [attr.maxlength]="InputLength"
    (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
    (keydown.enter)="onEnter($event.target.value)"
    (keydown)="onkeydown($event,$event.target.value)"
    (contextmenu)="onContextmenu($event)"
    (blur)="onBlur($event.target.value,$event)"
     data-col-index="0"/>
```

ctextboxcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef,Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor,NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, } from '@angular/forms';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { PlfDataSourceService } from '../../controls/plf-data-source.service'

const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide : NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CTextboxComponent),
  multi : true,
  };

@Component({
  selector: 'app-c-textbox',
  templateUrl: './c-textbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./c-textbox.component.css'],
  providers : [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CTextboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() label:String;
  @Input() mandatory:String;
  @Input() InputLength:any;
  @Input() inputFormat:String;
  @Input() format:String;
  @Input() precision:any;
  @Input() EventFlag:String="N";
  @Output() textBoxOnEnter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  val:String;
  private disabled: boolean;
  private onChange: Function;
  private onTouched: Function;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,private plfMain: PlfDataSourceService) { 
    this.onChange = (_: any) => { };
    this.onTouched = () => {};  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.inputFormat ==undefined) this.inputFormat="string";
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.val = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  onEnter(val)
  {
  }
  onContextmenu(evt)
  {
  }
  onkeydown(event,val)
  {    
  }

  validateNumber(evt) 
  {

  }
  validateNumeric(evt, value) 
  {
   }
  }
  onBlur(val,scope)
  {

  }
  validateEmail(field) {

  }
  validateMultipleEmailsCommaSeparated(value, seperator,scope) {    

  }
}
```

plf.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'
import { HttpRequestService } from '../utils/http-request.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlfDataSourceService {

  cueForm = this.fb.group({});


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private httpService: HttpRequestService,private routerLink: Router,) {};

  onScreenLoad(activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) 

    this.httpService.configRequestDataWithHeaders(requestData, 'post', '').subscribe(
        (response) => {
        this.cueForm.patchValue(response['hdrcache'][0]);
        for (var key in response['hdrcache'][0]) {
        if (response['hdrcache'][0][key] == '') {
          this.cueForm.patchValue({'strCalendarCodeFrom': response['hdrcache'][0]['strCalendarCodeFrom']});
        }

        }
      );



}
```

Comment: can you show sample code?

Comment: for (var key in response['hdrcache'][0]) {
        if (response['hdrcache'][0][key] == '') {
          this.cueForm.patchValue({'strCalendarCodeFrom': ' ' });
        } After looping the response im checking for null condition then im using patchValue for setting null value .Even if console my cueForm.value there the value is empty but only in form textbox view null value is not updating..

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/51756515/5366038

Comment: thanks i referred the link for the first time null  gets updated ,from second time on words its not updating the view..if i press f5 and try  again same happens

Comment: For info i am using ControlValueAccessor in my form

Comment: @ysk, when suggesting an edit make a more descriptive edit summary. Say the code came from OP within comments, now I had to go here to check where the code came from.

Comment: please paste your code so we can help you in a better-scoped way. Without watching your code I'd say to u to make sure you have a form control inside your form group and set the value accessing like this.cueForm.myFormControl.setValue('desired_value'). Thanks @Luuklag

Comment: i have updated my code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

finally i found answer for the issue ..need to subscribe valueChanges method to update the view using patch Value.

```
 this.cueForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    this.cueForm.patchValue(data, { emitEvent: false });
  })
```

Comment: some more explanation of this solution would go a long way

Answer (score 0):

Although patch value does work for setting a form control value. You can try this if it helps:

```
this.myForm.controls['name'].setValue('abcd');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203251/discussion-on-answer-by-mridul-formgroup-patchvalue-is-not-updating-the-text-box).

Answer (score 0):

Your Form should be like this

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
name : new FormControl("")
});
```

then you can set the value like this

```
this.myForm.controls['name'].setValue(<your value>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
this.myForm.patchValue({
  name: null
});

After setting `null` value to name property try `console.log(this.myForm.value);`
name property having `null` value. But after putting value into name input value get replaced with whatever your given input.

Comment: for (var key in response['hdrcache'][0]) {
        if (response['hdrcache'][0][key] == '') {
          this.cueForm.patchValue({ 'strCalendarCodeFrom': null });
        }
         else {
        
         }

      } then if i console this.cueform.value im getting {strCalendarCodeFrom: null, strCalenderDesc: "", strStatus: ""}  but in view still value is there .I have tried all possible ways

Comment: Please provide sample code or https://stackblitz.com/ you tried so far.